# How do I differentiate between sender and receiver in an chat app Laravel?

Tags: database, laravel-5, eloquent, chat

I am making a private(one to one) chat app in Laravel 5.7.
The problem is with schema I think. If **user1** is logged in and he creates a new conversation with **user2**. That would be created with **conversation_id=1**.
Next time when **user2** is logged in lets assume he will be finding his **ID** in sender column and he won't find his **ID** in sender_column, new conversation will be created which shouldn't be created because for creating the new conversation we have to check in sender and receiver column both.

Here is my schema

```
    =======User Table========
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    =============Chat Table=============
    Schema::create('chats', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user1_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('user1_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user2_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('user2_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    ===============Messages Table================
    Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('chat_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('chat_id')->references('id')->on('chats');
        $table->text('messages');
        $table->timestamps();

    });
```

Maybe you understand it by this.

```
Users                            Chats                                
id    name          chat_id    user1_id    user2_id
1     Mark             1           1           2
2     David            2           2           1
3     Henzard          3           2           3
                       4           3           2
```

Please suggest me a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have overlooked one or more complexities with the schema, but I came up with the following.

**users** -
Keep your existing users table.

**conversations** -
This will represent a single conversation, the initiating user, and the date the conversation started.

```
- id
- user_id           # user who initiated conversation
- created_at
```

**conversation_user** -
This will represent each user who is a part of the conversation. Whilst your requirements state that each conversation is between two users, this structure would allow you to have group conversations in the future too - should that ever be required.

Optionally, you could add a `read_at` timestamp to store the date/time the user last read the conversation. This could then be used to infer whether a user has unread messages in the conversation.

```
- id
- conversation_id
- user_id
- read_at           # when user last read conversation
- created_at
```

**messages** -
This will represent a single message in the conversation. Only the sending user needs to be recorded, because the users who can read the message are dictated by the `conversation_user` table.

```
- id
- conversation_id
- user_id           # user who sent message
- message
- created_at
- updated_at
```

Comment: So how would I get user conversation in which he is involved? Do I have to get check in both tables for that?

Comment: Can you clarify, are you asking how to get all the conversations a single user is involved with? Or how to get a specific conversation?

Comment: Lets assume if Mark is logged in with his account. I want to get all the messages in which Mark is involved whether he is sender or receiver. Do I have to check in both conversation and conversation_user table to get those messages in which he is involved.

Comment: No, I would add both the sender and receiver to the `conversation_user` table.

Comment: So should I make user_id in conversation_user table an array to store both sender and reciever?

Comment: No, just create one row for each user participating in the conversation.